# Prevent parameter encoding in controller spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, urlencode

I'm trying to write a (failing) controller spec for a parameter containing a forward slash:

```
# products_controller_spec.rb 
it "accepts parameters with a forward slash" do
  get :show, id: 'foo/bar'
  expect(response).to be_success
  expect(response).to render_template('show')
end
```

This should *fail*, since there is no matching route for '/products/foo/bar':

```
# routes.rb
resources :products, only: [:index, :show]
```

However, it passes, because the parameter `foo/bar` is URL-encoded before the request makes it to the controller:

```
# products_controller.rb
def show
  Rails.logger.debug(request.env['PATH_INFO'])
end
```

yields this in `test.log`:

```
I, [2015-05-13T13:33:16.410943 #12962]  INFO -- : Processing by ProductsController#show as HTML
I, [2015-05-13T13:33:16.411029 #12962]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"id"=>"foo/bar"}
...
D, [2015-05-13T13:33:16.412717 #12962] DEBUG -- : /products/foo%2Fbar/
I, [2015-05-13T13:33:16.413885 #12962]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 3ms (Views: 0.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

Note the URL-encoded `%2F` instead of `/` in the raw request. Short of stubbing out the request object, how can I make an rspec `get` request without having it encode the request parameter for me?

Comment: you're passing the id `foo/bar`, *not* calling the route. Isn't this supposed to happen?

Comment: And how would I call the route in a controller spec?

Comment: Are you simply trying to test that the route `foo/bar` won't route anywhere?

Comment: Because I don't know what your test is supposed to do except `it "works"`

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to determine via a *failing* spec, before I add route globbing to enable id parameters containing a `/`.

Comment: Fair enough, I made the test description more explicit :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77719/discussion-between-thechamp-and-thilo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like what you're actually trying to test is that `/products/foo/bar` is routed to the show action of the `ProductsController` with `"foo/bar"` as the `id` parameter.

Under the covers, `rspec-rails` controller tests use `ActionController::TestCase`, which provides an `assert_routing` assertion. In `rspec-rails` you can use this assertion with the [`#route_to`](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails#route_to) expectation, like so:

```
expect(get: "/products/foo/bar").to route_to(controller: "products", action: "show", id: "foo/bar")
```